# Averaging Highest Three Values of multiple cells in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

I have two columns of data. I need the formula to pull the three highest values from both columns and average them.

55,000.00
**87,769.12**
**85,839.97**

56,650.00
58,349.50
60,099.99
61,902.98
63,760.07
65,672.88
**67,643.06**

These values will change and the formula needs to analyze all of the cells constantly to pull the three highest and average. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This formula will do this:

```
=AVERAGE(LARGE($A:$A,ROW(A1:A3)))
```

You need to enter it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

In your specific example, use this formula:

```
=AVERAGE(LARGE((C11:D13,M12:N18),ROW(1:3)))
```

Comment: THE DATA IS IN THE FOLLOWING CELLS C11 THROUGH C13 AND M12 THROUGH M18. IT IS NOT IN A ROW BUT IS IN A COLUMN. THIS IS THE FORMULA I HAVE TRIED BUT THE RESULT SEEMS TO ALWAYS BE THE LAST AMOUNT IN CELL M18 FOR SOME REASON.  =AVERAGE(LARGE(($C$11:$C$13,$M$12:$M$18),3))

Comment: Sorry, no shouting, I use Caps for work constantly. I used the formula and it gave me a number but it is incorrect. It seems to only pull the highest number instead of the 3 highest and average them. The result of the formula is 87769.12 which is the value in C12. Any ideas?

Comment: most likely you did not enter it with ctrl-shift-enter! :-)